# Posted question under guest account, can't link to my new account?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question [How do I clarify that the gift someone gave me is mine when they are asking for it back?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/12420/how-do-i-clarify-that-the-gift-someone-gave-me-is-mine-when-they-are-asking-for) under a guest account. I want to accept an answer/comment but I'm not able to because, after I signed up something weird happened and the signup didn't work. I tried signing up again with the same email but then it reverted me to some other user (my other stackoverflow profile... which I didn't use here on the interpersonal exchange because.. I just wanted to post anonymously)

So I turned to meta after making this (different) account to try to make this post but, alas, I can't post to meta without at least 5 rep.

So here I am. I kind screwed the pooch on this one. Can anyone fix this? If not, can someone upvote and accept [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/12422/15924) and upvote [this other answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/12421/15924) on my behalf?

Sorrrry

[image]

Comment: Hey trey, I flagged your question so that it could be migrated to meta, so now here it is, but other than that I don't know how to solve your problem... Our mods will be surely able to help you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the bottom of every page there's a "[contact](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link.

If you click on that link, one of the options is to request your accounts to be merged.

> If you need to delete your account, merge accounts, or have an issue that can't be addressed by meta, please use the form below:

Once the staff has done this, you'll be able to upvote and accept any answers you like.

If you want to keep the accounts separate, you won't be able to register using the same email address you use for your primary account, you'll need to use a secondary login option or a different email address.

Only you can accept an answer, so we couldn't do it for you even if you gave us permission.

Comment: Can the reputation for main and meta be different? For the OP, it shows (currently) 104 on meta and 114 on main.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I think the meta rep takes longer to update, so it's a caching issue. :)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the clarification.